# Create Test Coverage for jar file using Junit and Emma with command prompt

Tags: java, command-line, jar, junit, emma

I am provided with jar files which contains many classes without Main method. How to perform Test Coverage and generate results for all these classes using Junit and Emma ??

> java -cp MyJar.jar;. emmarun -cp path\emma.jar -report txt,html junit.textui.TestRunner MyTestClass

This command line is showing Class MyTestClass not found !! Also tried out.MyTestClass but still same problem.

Jar structure ---- MyJar.jar

```
             ---MetaInf-->manifest.mf

             ---out--->MyTestClass.class
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put `MyJar.jar` into the classpath of the `emmarun` invocation, it would seem.